# Index match function to return range category in Excel 2010

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010

I have defined categories in columns on which the values represent the ranges for each item (rows).

By using the query (column G), I want to know in which category the item ("yellow", 60) falls into. 60 is between 40 and 180 so category will be "ripe".

The category depends on the range, so for item "yellow" the ranges include: 2 < "young"<=40, 40<"ripe"<=180, 180<"old".

Does anybody know how i can solve this by `INDEX`/`MATCH` function?

[image]

Regards

Bien

Comment: I'm having trouble understanding your ranges since they don't seem to follow consistent rules.  In your example, the "young" value defines the bottom of its range, the "ripe" value defines the top of its range, "Perfect" has a value but has no range, and "old" has a range but doesn't exist.  You can make pretty much anything work in Excel if you define the rules, but the solutions are a lot simpler (single function vs. extensive logic), if the rules follow a consistent pattern (each value has the same meaning).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `INDEX` to pare out the row of numbers you want to make an approximate `MATCH` on.

[image: Ripe_Old]

The formula in G4 is,

`=INDEX($B$1:$D$1, MATCH($G$3, INDEX($B$2:$D$5, MATCH($G$2,$A$2:$A$5, 0), )))`

Note the extra comma leading to a blank *column_num* parameter on the inside `INDEX` function. This is important and tells `INDEX` you want the whole row from the block of numbers and not a single entry.

Comment: `"60 is between 40 and 180 so category will be "ripe"` - your answer outputs the category "perfect". Nearly!

Comment: @AndiMohr - I had a hard time balancing the OP's statement `2 < "young"<=40, 40<"ripe"<=180, 180<"old"` against what the posted image was since the description does not mention *perfect* and the image does not include *old*. If the image's categories are used, this should be correct as *60* is greater than 40 and less than 180. Before attempting correction, I'll let the OP rectify the discrepancy.

Comment: Fair point, I was just going on the text. Clarification needed!

Comment: Sorry about that, the categories should be young, ripe and old. the image is wrong. https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/-HOhI5fdX6ck/VJlYBEbTmyI/AAAAAAAANBI/9UaVndblcbs/w514-h124-no/Capture.PNG